# Insert into more tables based on the first inserted primary key

Tags: sql, insert

I have two tables. Products(**id_product**, name) and Images(id_image, **id_product**, image). 
How can i INSERT a product and it's categories in a single query, inserting the inserted id_product into the Images coresponding id_product.

- Product(1, 'Toy')
- Image(1, 1, 'image.jpg')
- Image(2, 1, 'image-2.jpg')
- Image(3, 1, 'image-3.jpg')

Something like this. I need it to be in a single query.

Comment: You cannot insert or update multiple tables in a single SQL statement.

Comment: there is no alternative? do i really have to INSERT;SELECT MAX;INSERT; ?

Comment: No, you don't need to select `MAX` - depending on RDBMS, there's usually a syntax for you to obtain the value of the last auto-generated ID. But you need multiple `INSERT`s for multiple tables.

Comment: Note that unless you lock the **ENTIRE** table in a transaction (which will make access serial), if multiple people are using the table at the same time `SELECT MAX(...)` may _not_ return the correct results.  If you have some unique natural key you could query based on that... but the db-provided utilities for getting most-recent-id is usually a better id.  These are db-specific (as @dasblinkenlight mentioned) - figure out what your db is, then report it here, or look around for similar questions about your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a store procedure to handle the sql statements

Comment: ....Not really helpful.  For one thing, it's not required to do so, and whatever he writes for the SP is going to use the _same_ utilities that other solutions require.